# Retrieve cookie VALUE in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, cookies

I'm trying to retrieve the cookie's value by simply calling its indexed position in the array, which is 1. However, I'm getting an error message saying 1 is an undefined offset? When I know for a fact it is in position 1. Am I missing something??

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM basketID" . $_COOKIE[1];
```

I've set the cookie like this

```
setcookie('visitUid',$uid,time()+60*60*24*7, '/');
```

$uid is a randomly generated number btw.

Comment: `$_COOKIE` is an associative array

Answer (score 3):

`$_COOKIE['visitUid']` is what you are looking for

Comment: Will this give me the value of $uid of which I assigned?

Comment: `setcookie`'s first parameter is the associative name, second is variable value. to access it use the associative name 'visitUid'.